# Solr charFilter doesn't allow Regex query [solr 7.6.0]

Tags: solr, lucene

I'm trying to run a regex query on a solr `solr.TextField` field. Is this mean to be supported on that field type?

For example, I'm searching `curl -g 'http://localhost:8983/solr/shard/select?rows=0&q=body:/hello/'` which returns > 0 results.

But when I switch it to `curl -g 'http://localhost:8983/solr/shard/select?rows=0&q=body:/h[aeiou]llo/'` i get 0 results?

```
<fieldType name="body_text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="false">
    <analyzer>
      <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="[^a-zA-Z0-9_@-]+" replacement=" "/>
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" rule="java" />
      <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="2" max="45"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<field name="body" type="body_text" uninvertible="true" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
```

When I add `debugQuery=true`, I see that my charFilter replacement is not allowing regex characters through:

```
"debug":{
    "rawquerystring":"body:/h[aeiou]llo/",
    "querystring":"body:/h[aeiou]llo/",
    "parsedquery":"RegexpQuery(body:/h aeiou llo/)",
    "parsedquery_toString":"body:/h aeiou llo/",
    "explain":{},
    "QParser":"LuceneQParser",
```

Comment: How does just `h.llo` work? Does that give you the entries? i.e. could it be an issue with `[]` being escaped and being considered as part of the expression instead of as a character group? (shouldn't be the case when using curl - but maybe your shell does something magical? Check the Solr log for what query is actually received)

Comment: @MatsLindh, no `h.llo` also does not work. It seems like once I add any regex-like special characters (encoded or not) i get zero results returned. The response shows the correctly-formatted query

Comment: which Solr version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PatterReplaceCharFilterFactory is removing all special characters, matching your pattern, from the regex. Therefore the "[" and "]" are removed from the query and you are seeing zero documents found. The query `h[aeiou]llo` becomes `h aeiou llo`.

A way to keep both your pattern replace and regex is using the PatternReplaceFilterFactory. Therefore:

```
<fieldType name="body_text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="false">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" rule="java" />
      <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="[^a-zA-Z0-9_@-]+" replacement=" "/>
      <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="2" max="45"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Just check if this works for your use-case.

Comment: i'm getting the same result using `solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory`. I've included the debug results in my question.

Comment: Can you also share the debugQuery with the solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory?
I've tried it locally and I obtain: "rawquerystring":"body:/h[aeiu]llo/", "querystring":"body:/h[aeiu]llo/", "parsedquery":"RegexpQuery(body:/h[aeiu]llo/)", "parsedquery_toString":"body:/h[aeiu]llo/". Can you also tell me which query parser and which Solr version are you using?

Comment: I've tried also with your Solr version (I see 7.6.0 now in the question title) and the analyzer I put in my answer seems working giving the same debugged query as the comment before.
Sure you have removed the old charFilter and put only the new one? Have you correctly reloaded the core after the schema changes?

Comment: that fixed the regex query, but broke other queries. I'm looking into it now,  I wonder if it has to do with the difference between `<filter>` and `<charFilter>`?